Writing commands in dialogue
I have three characters Alice, Bill and Charlie.
Alice is the captain of the group and is giving a command.
What I am trying to convey: Alice commands Charlie to lock the door.
How do I write it with a dialog tag after the quotation?

Alice told Charlie, "Lock the door."

is okay, but I want something more like.

"Lock the door," said Alice to Charlie.

Any better suggestions?

It is unnecessary to state in the dialogue tag that Alice is giving a command. The form and content of her utterance make it clear that it is a command. This sets you free to use other dialogue tags that describe how Alice gives her order (whisper, scream, etc.) – or none.
While it is perfectly fine to use dialogue tags to let the reader know who is speaking, dialogue will quickly become boring if you just report who says what, like in a play:
Play

CHARLIE   I got the gun, captain.
ALICE   Good. Lock the door.

Prose written like a play

"I got the gun, captain," Charlie said.
"Good. Lock the door," Alice commanded.

To write more vividly, begin by imagining the scene. What has happened before Alice is giving the order? Where is everyone in relation to the door and to each other when she gives it? What are they doing at the moment? And so on. If you experience the scene from inside like this, you will automatically and easily embed the dialogue in action and description.
For example, how do Bill and Charlie know that Alice wants Charlie to lock the door and not Bill? Alice will have to indicate the person she wants to execute her order, if it's relevant. She can name Charlie:

"Charlie, lock the door."

Or she can use her gaze or gestures to address him:

Alice looked at Charlie. "Lock the door," she mouthed.

I don't know your story, so I cannot propose a good solution, but to me this reads more interesting than:

"Lock the door," Alice commanded Charlie.

But if you absolutely want to have a dialogue tag like the one in your question,

"Lock the door," Alice told Charlie.

is perfectly fine, as is any other synonym of command:

"Lock the door," Alice ordered / instructed / bid Charlie.


You can do this indirectly, without dialogue.

Alice directed Charlie to lock the door.
Once he had, she said, "We have a problem..."

Or:

Alice looked up and met Charlie's eyes. "Lock the door."
She waited until he had, and returned. "We have a problem..."

You do not have to be concise here. People that read fiction do not mind reading, if it helps them imagine the scene.

Go Deeper
Get beyond the simple action to the motivation, and that might make the best path forward more obvious.
What tone is Alice using? A command can be icy, or angry, or urgent, or pompous, or any number of things. She has chosen a tone, and that probably says something about her.
Why is Alice giving the command? Has Charlie frozen up in fear? He hasn't seen the danger? Alice is doing something unexpected?
Examples
Charlie froze:
 Charlie's eyes were wide, and his breath came heavy. 
 Alice realized he was in shock.
"Charlie," she said, voice clear and calm. "Lock the door."
 He blinked.
"Now," she said.

We need the insight into Alice's reasoning for the order to make sense. So Alice observes his expression, decides what that means, and takes an action. The action - the choice - Alice makes is to speak calmly to keep Charlie from panicking.
The whole thing gives us the impression of Alice as a leader who is insightful, empathetic, and decisive.
Alice is betraying someone, and no one else was in on it:
Denise was running for her life. The killer was close, but the safety of the door was closer.
When Alice spoke, her voice was hard as steel and just as cold.
"Lock the door."
"What?" Charlie asked, stunned.
"Did I stutter?" She snarled. "Lock the door."

In the second example, we describe Alice's voice before she speaks. This helps the reader to read it in the tone that you intend. It also serves as a kind of mini-foreshadowing - it's not a nice voice, and we know that before we read the dialog.
The use of sarcasm and the word "snarled" makes the final line very sharp.
The impression we get here is that Alice is decisive, but also cruel. Again, emphasis is on the choice Alice is making (to be cruel to both Denise and Charlie).
Final Thoughts
We never need to use the phrase "Alice told Charlie" because the context is always clear. But sometimes the dialog comes before the tags, and sometimes it's the other way around, depending on which version serves the purpose better.
